# How to log output to maillog?

Tags: bash, logs, email, logger

On my current Debian setup, I have a file /var/log/mail.log which Dovecot, Postfix, and Spamassassin's spamd all output messages to.  I know that the `logger` command can output to syslog, but is there some command that easily lets me output to the mail log from a bash script, or do I have to manually open it and append to it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the stuff I was logging using `logger` was *also* being logged out to my `/var/log/mail.log` file anyway.  I think this is becasue (on Debian anyway) the default logging configuration in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` defines the default log for the mail 'facility' to be that mail.log file, and my script was indeed logging to the mail 'facility'.  This seems to make `logger` log both to mail.log and to syslog.

Answer (score 0):

"Manually open and append" in a bash context is pretty simple:

```
mycommand >> /var/log/mail.log
```

Standard output from `mycommand` goes to the file. If you put this at the beginning of a script:

```
exec 1>&2&>> /var/log/mail.log
```

Standard output (1) & error (2) for everything in the rest of the script will be appended to the file.

If you want to initially truncate the file (ie, not append to pre-existing content), use `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: Right, but looking at the other stuff that's been logged to mail.log, it has the exact same format as stuff that's been logged to syslog.  Presumably some library is being used to output that, rather than each line's string being manually constructed.  Is there no way to generate this log line string from bash?